# Чем отличается (char*) от *(char**) при приведении типов?

Tags: c

Чем отличается (char*) от *(char**) при приведении типов? В каких случаях использовать какой способ приведения к указателю на char?

Привести тип void* к типу char*. Всегда просто использовал char*, но сегодня преподаватель при обьяснении материала привёл void* к char* при помощи конструкции *(char**)

Comment: А *что именно* вы хотите приводить?...

Comment: @Harry Привести тип void* к типу char*. Всегда просто использовал char*, но сегодня преподаватель при обьяснении материала привёл void* к char* при помощи конструкции * 
 (char * *)

Comment: Точно `*(char**)`, а не `*(char**)&`?

Answer (score 8):

О какой-то аналогии между `(char*)` от `*(char**)` можно говорить только если второй вариант имеет вид `*(char**) &`. Без `&` это совершенно разные вещи и сравнивать их бессмысленно.

Формально, приведением типов является только первый вариант. Второй вариант - это никакое не "приведение типов". Это - переинтерпретация памяти (type punning), которая лишь использует приведение типа в качестве промежуточного шага.

Результат первого варианта - rvalue. Результат второго варианта - lvalue. Это - фундаментальное отличие, из которого проистекают все остальные отличия.

В общем случае доступ к переинтерпретированной памяти приводит к неопределенному поведению. Из этого правила есть исключения, но переинтерпретация между `void *` и `char *` через `*(char**) &` таким исключением не является. Переинтерпретацию между `void *` и `char *` можно выполнить через `union`, но не через приведение типа.